# How to find the limit without L'Hospital rule

Tags: calculus, analysis, limits

Find the limit
$$\lim_{x\to\infty} x\left[\left(1+\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{4x^2}+\frac{1}{8x^3}\right)^{1/3}-1\right].$$
I assume that L'Hospital rule here is useless and something else must be done.

Comment: With the hint of Quang Hoang, I get $1+h+h^2+h^3=\frac{1-h^3}{1-h}\implies\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{(1+h+h^2+h^3)^{1/3}-1}{2h}=\frac12\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{\big(\frac{1-h^3}{1-h}\big)^{1/3}-1}{h}=\frac12\frac{d}{dh}\big(\frac{1-h^3}{1-h}\big)^{1/3}\Bigr|_{h=0}=\frac12\frac13=\frac16$

Answer (score 3):

Let $h=\frac1{2x}$, the limit becomes
$$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(1+h+h^2+h^3)^{1/3}-1}{2h}.$$
Does it look familiar? Hint: It's the derivative of some function.

Answer (score 2):

By the Taylor series

$$(1+u)^{\alpha}\sim_0 1+\alpha u$$
and even with mental algebra we see that the desired limit is $\frac16$.

Comment: Can you please be more specific? My mental abilities are limited and I can't see that the limit is 1/6.

Comment: Not to be picky, but to me, using Taylor instead of L'Hospital is much like cheating :-)

Comment: Anyway Taylor is something else as the OP request :-) @QuangHoang

Comment: Take $\alpha=\frac13$ and $u=\frac{1}{2x}+\frac{1}{4x^2}+\frac{1}{8x^3}$ and use the Taylor approximation as in my answer. @martin